# SOX LAME and php fire done signal?

Tags: php, lame, sox

Hi I am using SOX in the following manner with php:

> $thesong = 67;
>
> $theString = "1.wav 2.wav 2.wav 1.wav";
>
> exec("./sox $theString $thesong.wav");

It seems to be be working very good, Then I do the following:

> exec("./lame $thesong.wav $thesong.mp3");

Again this works fine, but is there any way to tell when both `SOX` and `LAME` have completed the encoding?

I mean do they send out a "I Am Done" signal?

Something like:

```
if(soxdone && lamedone)
{
  //further processing?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this:

```
if(exec("./lame $thesong.wav $thesong.mp3") && exec("./sox $theString $thesong.wav"))
{
   //further processing 
}
```